# how to grab a specific row from sql3 tables

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

Im trying to make a program so that the user can input a country, and the program can output the entire row of information using tkinter and sqlite 3. Here is my code so far, please let me know if you see any other holes in my code,and thank you in advance! :)

```py
    from  tkinter import *
    bobert=Tk()
    bobert.geometry("600x600")
    import sqlite3
    
    connection = sqlite3.connect('covidproject.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    country_name=StringVar()
    
    label1=Label(bobert,text="World Covid Stats",fg="black",font=("sand script",20))
    label1.place(x=183,y=100)
    
    label2=Label(bobert,text="Name of Country:",fg="black",font=("sand script",15))
    label2.place(x=130,y=150)
    
    n=Entry(bobert,textvariable=country_name)
    n.place(x=310,y=158)
    
    def subby():
        answer=country_name.get()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM covid WHERE name LIKE '"+answer+"'")
        data=cursor.fetchall()
    
    submit=Button(bobert, text="SUBMIT", fg="black",font=("arial",13),command=subby)
    submit.place(x=260,y=200)
    
    bobert.mainloop
```

Comment: Whenever you ask something specific always add the error that you got

Comment: can u actually describe ur table? also note that last line of ur code, ur shud say `bobert.mainloop()`

Comment: The table has the name of a bunch of countries, the number of covid cases, dead, recovered, active, and confirmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I would recommend is passing it as parameters like

```
def subby():
        answer=country_name.get()
        l_answer = answer.capitalize()
        sql_command = "SELECT * FROM covid WHERE `name` = ?;"
        values = (l_answer,)
        cursor.execute(sql_command,values)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
```

Since you are using `=` it should be noted that the string must be converted to exactly like the details in your table. So using `answer.capitalize()` will capitalize the first letter of your entry and search accordingly to it.

Alternatively, if you want to make code shorter you can avoid the parametric substitution here and also use recursive definition for the variable

```
def subby():
        answer=country_name.get()
        answer = answer.capitalize()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM covid WHERE `name` = ?;",(answer,))
        data = cursor.fetchall()
```

Happy coding :D

Comment: I put that into the function instead of "cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM covid WHERE name LIKE '"+answer+"'")" but I got an error that says "OperationalError: near "%": syntax error"

Comment: that is not the correct way of passing as a parameter, copy paste this code into that and try?i have updated the ans so u can copy dis ans and replace ur function

Comment: sorry- this is probably a really stupid question but do i copy and paste it into the function or somewhere else?thanks!

Comment: i have updated the ans so u can copy dis ans and replace ur whole function

Comment: it still came out as "Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\minio\pythiin\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/minio/Downloads/sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3320300/sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3320300/byebyebirdie.py", line 33, in subby
    cursor.execute(sql_command,values)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error"

Comment: this time there werent any errors:) I printed (data) but it was an empty list, am i printing the wrong variable?

Comment: it means there is no result, like u need to enter the exact same name as u used in ur table like Japan or japan. it is case sensitive

Comment: for some reason when i web scraped the web site there a star in from of it, so i earased the star from the data base and typed in Japan and it workedddd:))))

Comment: okay so ill update the code once more and try copy pasting it such that even if u use japan it'll work

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the variable `answer` contains the name of the country.
All you need to do is apply formatting

Instead of this

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM covid WHERE name LIKE '"+answer+"'")
```

Try

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM covid WHERE name = {}".format(answer))
```

Comment: I just did that and it told me and there was no column named 'japan'. Japan is the country I inputted

Comment: Then either japan is not in your table or you spelled it wrong

Comment: If all of your inputs are capitalized then answer variable can be capitalized to match the same.

Comment: Just use `answer.capitalize()`

Answer (score 0):

You can always use f-sting for formatting.

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM covid WHERE name = {answer}")
```